# Запрос в MS SQL 2017: выбрать значения из строки, которые не повторялись ранее

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Имеется таблица:

```
A  | B   | С    
-------------   
1  | 12  |      
2  | 45  | 2    
3  | 49  | 3    
4  | 57  | 2, 4 
5  | 80  | 7    
6  | 91  | 2, 3 
7  | 109 | 9    
8  | 115 | 3, 8, 10
```

И т.д.
Мне нужно из этой таблицы получить таблицу, в столбце `C` которой будут значения, которые не повторялись ранее. Т.е. для строки `A=4` мы убираем двойку из столбца `С`, так как она уже была в строке `А=2`. Из строки `6` убираем и 2, и 3, так как они были ранее и т.д.

Вот должна быть такая таблица:

```
A  | B   | С 
------------- 
1  | 12  |       
2  | 45  | 2     
3  | 49  | 3     
4  | 57  | 4     
5  | 80  | 7     
6  | 91  |       
7  | 109 | 9     
8  | 115 | 8, 10
```

P.S. БД MS SQL 2017

Comment: Нормализуйте. Нумеруйте в пределах группы. Выберите первые. Соберите обратно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

смотрите куда-нибудь в эту сторону

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT a, b
          , trim(value) AS value
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY trim(value) ORDER BY a)  AS rn
    FROM x 
    CROSS APPLY string_split(c, ',')  
)
SELECT a, b
     , STRING_AGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(value AS int))
FROM data
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY a,b
ORDER BY a
```

здесь правда будут пропущены пустые строки (`A=6`), кроме первой. но можете приджойнить это к исходной таблице,  или придумать другой вариант.

[sql-фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c147e/9/0)